# (Pandas) Group by one column and keep only the rows where another column is the max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with 6 columns, two of them being "date" and "time". For each date, I want to keep only the rows with the maximum time value.
For example, below the date is on the left and the time is on the right. 
I want to only keep all of the rows where the time is 1925.

```
20200109    1925
20200109    1925
20200109    1925
20200109    1925
20200109    1925
20200109    1925
20200109    1830
20200109    1830
20200109    1830
20200109    1830
20200109    1830
```

I have tried so many solutions sorting and using groupby, such as `dataframe.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.time == x.time.max(),['date','time']])`

but this only returns the date and time columns. I want all 6 columns in my result

Edit: I want to keep all of the dates associated with the maximum time.

Comment: `df.sort_values('time').drop_duplicates('date', keep='last')`

Comment: This only returns one date and one time value. I want to keep all of the dates associated with the maximum time. I should have clarified this

Comment: `df[df['time'] == df.groupby('date')['time'].transform('max')]`

Comment: same problem still :(

Comment: 1. Why did you include `['date','time']` in your `loc` if you want all 6 columns? 2. My comment above keeps all the rows with maximum time **within a date**. If you want all dates that have (global) maximum time, then just do `df[df['time']==df['time'].max()]`?

Comment: ahhhhh I understand. I removed `['date','time']` from the code I included in my post, and now it is perfect. I didn't fully understand how it was working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
dates = [20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200109, 20200110]
times = [1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1830, 1830, 1830, 1830, 1830, 1930]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'times':times})

filt = df.groupby(['dates'])['times'].max().to_frame().reset_index()
final = pd.merge(df,filt,on=['dates','times'])

final 
      dates  times
  0  20200109   1925
  1  20200109   1925
  2  20200109   1925
  3  20200109   1925
  4  20200109   1925
  5  20200109   1925
  6  20200110   1930
```

I think even if you add more columns to `df`, `final` would have the extra columns as you desire.